# Error: Could not find or load main class PostgresWithJDBCConnection

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, postgresql-14

I am trying to run a java file which tests whether my java file is well connected to postgresql@14 using JDBC(jar file) in VSCode environment. But I am facing some problems.

First, the tree visualization of my current directory(called `FamilyCalendar`) is as follows:

```
.
├── DateBox.java
├── FamilyCalendar.java
├── PostgresWithJDBCConnection.class
├── PostgresWithJDBCConnection.java
├── PostgresWithJDBCDelete.java
├── PostgresWithJDBCInsert.java
├── PostgresWithJDBCSelect.java
├── PostgresWithJDBCUpdate.java
├── StringManager.java
└── postgresql-42.6.0.jar
```

And the following is `PostgresWithJDBCConnection.java` source code.

```java
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class PostgresWithJDBCConnection {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/dob", "dob",
                "MY_PASSWD")) {
            System.out.println("Connection established successfully");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.print(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

To test the connection, I tried both ways; terminal environment and VSCode UI.

### Terminal Environment

I tried the following commands.

```
javac -cp './postgresql-42.6.0.jar' PostgresWithJDBCConnection.java
java -cp './postgresql-42.6.0.jar' PostgresWithJDBCConnection
```

Then, for the second command line(java -cp ..), the error occurs;

```
Error: Could not find or load main class PostgresWithJDBCConnection
```

But as you can see my tree visualization of the working directory, there is definitely such class file.

### VSCode UI

After I failed with the previous one, I just decided to click the `run` button(▶️) on the right-top of VSCode, but the error occurs as well:

```
[Running] cd "/Users/dob/Justin/FamilyCalendar/" && javac PostgresWithJDBCConnection.java && java PostgresWithJDBCConnection
No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/dob
[Done] exited with code=0 in 1.208 seconds
```

Seemingly it's because I didn't clarify the `.jar` file(for JDBC) - but does it mean I always have to manually clarify the path?

Can anyone explain what the problem is and let me know how to solve it?

Thanks for reading! Please let me know if my description was insufficient for you to handle the problem.

The thing is that I successfully run everything with all the environments and files the exact same in virtual machine that uses Ubuntu - this may not be that informational though.

Comment: Your first variant looks for PostgresWithJDBCConnection somewhere in the jars you put in your classpath, but fails. Your second try lacks the driver-jar in the class-path. Very probably the next error will be caused by not telling java in which package your PostgresWithJDBCConnection is.

Comment: @GyroGearloose Alright Gyro, thank you for giving me some hints. In short, you mean I should register the path of the driver-jar file in the class-path? After that, I also have to tell it which package my java file is? I don't know how to do though.

Comment: Try running some simple programs, with no dependencies, from the command line. Once you have that working, come back to this program.

Comment: @tgdavies I tried to run test.java that prints "adsf" via both terminal running and VSCode UI (clicking 'run' button), and both work!

Comment: Okay. Next step is to keep the same simple program, but add the postgresql jar to the class path (as you did before) and see if the program still runs and prints "adsf".

Comment: @tgdavies NO WAY! It suddenly doesn't work with the jar file - ```javac -cp './postgresql-42.6.0.jar' test.java``` (no problem with this) then ```java -cp './postgresql-42.6.0.jar' test``` raises ```Error: Could not find or load main class test``` error. Do you have any idea about this happening? Thanks for your help, I might be getting closer to the solution?

Comment: Once you set the class path to *only* look at the jar file, it can't see the `.class` file you are trying to run. You'll need to add the directory that your class file hierarchy is in to the class path (remember how packages are treated).

Comment: @tgdavies Oh Lord. I tried ```java -cp './postgresql-42.6.0.jar:./' PostgresWithJDBCConnection``` and now it works! Thank you so much legend. For this time, I clarified both paths for each ```.jar``` and ```.class```but still don't know how to add the parent directory ```FamilyCalendar``` to class path permanently(?) so that my VSCode environment automatically recognizes both files and runs my java file by just clicking 'run' button. Would you help me with this as well? Even if you can't, again I really appreciate your kind instructions.